# Dictionary only Storing One Key and Value/Overwriting Previous Key and Value

Tags: swift, dictionary, memory, logic

I am currently using a dictionary to store the index values of segmented controls which I have in each TableView cell. Each segmented control has a tag that corresponds to the index path of the row that it is in.

In the dictionary, the key is the segmented control's tag (or the index path of the row which the segmented control is in, however you please), and the value is the index of the segmented control itself (i.e. option 0 corresponds to index 0 and option 1 corresponds to index 1).

So, the dictionary would look something like this if there were three rows and the first segmented control had option 0 selected, the second segmented control had option 1 selected, and the third segmented control had option 1 selected:

```
[0:0, 1:1, 2:1]
```

However, this is not what I get. When I print the dictionary, the only value in it is the key and index of the button which I had just pressed. Something like this:

```
 [0:0]
 [1:1]
 [2:1]
```

If I had selected option 0 for segmented control 1, option 1 for segmented control 2, and option 1 for segmented control 3 in that order.

Here is my code for reference:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)


    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Sample Item"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
        frame: CGRect.zero,
        titles: [
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ])


actionButton.delegate = self
cell.addSubview(nameLabel)
cell.addSubview(actionButton)
actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-160-[v1]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel, "v1": actionButton]));
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-60-[v0]-60-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": actionButton]))

actionButton.tag = indexPath.row


    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

```
extension MyTableViewController: YSSegmentedControlDelegate {
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt     index: Int) {
    var indexToTag = [Int:Int]()
    indexToTag[index] = segmentedControl.tag

    // Looking up tag
    let tag = indexToTag[index]

    print("\(indexToTag)")

}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}
```

}

As well as a picture of my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMUJ.png

Thanks, 
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Revised:  It looks to me like you are getting a new dictionary before each

```
indexToTag[index] = segmentedControl.tag
```

The code example uses a variable, indexToTag, whose scope is local to the function and does not survive.

If one could move the dictionary (indexToTag) from inside the function,
but still in the extension,then the stored property for the instance could be remember.

The problem with that is swift extensions do not directly permit stored properties in extensions.
(Check entries in Stack Overflow for stored properties and swift extensions).

The challenge is getting your code to have the desired class or instance variable to remember the dictionary contents.

Here is a sandbox example using a trivial extension.  The dictionary is outside the extension.

I don't know how your code might best accomplish something similar.

```
import Foundation

var indexToTag = [Int:Int]()

extension String {
   func control( index: Int, scTag: Int) {
      indexToTag[index] = scTag

      let tag = indexToTag[index]!
      print(" tag is \(tag)    indexToTag  contains: \(indexToTag)")
   }
}

let bst = String()

bst.control(index: 0, scTag: 0)
bst.control(index: 1, scTag: 1)
bst.control(index: 2, scTag: 1)
```

which prints

```
 tag is 0    indexToTag  contains: [0: 0]
 tag is 1    indexToTag  contains: [0: 0, 1: 1]
 tag is 1    indexToTag  contains: [2: 1, 0: 0, 1: 1]
```

Note that indexToTag is a dictionary, thus the contents do not have the original order of insertion.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was overthinking it a little bit. The scope of the function was the problem. I declared the dictionary outside of the extension and it worked wonderfully. You were a really big help, I was worried I wouldn't be able to get that to work.